# Как сгруппировать большое количество данных по часам?

Tags: mysql, sql

Такой запрос вернёт все записи за период, а нужно получить по одной за каждый час.

```
select
  *
from
  test
where
  obj_id = 297
  AND data between "2006-06-01 00:00:00" AND "2013-08-06 23:00:00";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD**

```
group by year(data), month(data), day(data), hour(data)
```

А по каким полям и как агрегировать множество записей в одном часу, думаю решите :-)

Comment: @Чад То ли я не так понял, то ли вы. На всякий случай уточню. Надо получить все 100500 записей за весь период с разницей в один час.

    group by hour(data)

Даст 24 записи(по одной на каждый час)

Comment: Может тогда

     group by date(data), hour(data)

Comment: @zenith, Ну, раз поняли идею, в чём проблема? :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(data, "%Y-%m-%d %H")
```